# How to get crisp css rotated text?

Tags: css, transform, rotation

I'm using css3 transforms in the ayout of a website to get some 'jaunty' angles and it's really impacting the legibility of the text. Here's an example of what I'm talking about...

http://rotatetest.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com/index.html

the text in the above example makes use of css transforms and a jquery plugin for comparison, both produce the same jaggy results.

Is there any techniques for getting smoother results, perhaps something using canvas???

Comment: BTW, you could have put that on JSFiddle more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try font-smooth but I doubt that this will solve your problem:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-smooth

(BTW: The jQuery and CSS examples both use the same css transform so they are equivalent - no need to post both)